# traer datos a partir de dos condiciones en mongodb

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

//Quiero traer los mensajes de una base de datos mongo a el cliente, lo que intento hacer es que a trabes de una consulta usando mongoose agregarle dos condicione, les dejo mi codigo

```
const { mensajes } = ('./models');

let chat = await mensajes.find({de: , para: }); //aqui la consulta usando mongoose
```

Quiero traer los documentos donde `de` sea igual al usuario emisor y `para` sea igual al usuario receptor o viceversa, me familiarizo mas con base de datos SQL y quiero hacer algo parecido a esto

```
SELET * FROM mensajes WHERE de = emisor and para = receptor or de = receptor and para = emisor
```

busque expresiones regulares en la documentacion de mongodb pero la verdad que sigo sin entender, les agradeceria si me ayudan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución seria utilizar los [operadores de consultas lógicas](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-logical/), por ejemplo, así:

```
let emisor = 'a';
let receptor = 'b';

let chat = await mensajes.find({
  $or: [{
    $and: [{de: emisor, para: receptor}]
  }, {
    $and: [{de: receptor, para: emisor}]
  }]
});
```

Lo que seria equivalente a:

```
SELET * FROM mensajes WHERE (de = emisor AND para = receptor) 
    OR (de = receptor AND para = emisor)
```